# Uniform convergence of $f'_n/f_n$

Tags: complex-analysis

The following is the proof of Hurwit'z theorm in [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_%28complex_analysis%29)

> Let f be an analytic function on an open subset of the complex plane
>   with a zero of order m at z0, and suppose that {fn} is a sequence of
>   functions converging uniformly on compact subsets to f. Fix some ρ > 0
>   such that f(z) ≠ 0 in 0 < |z−z0| < ρ. Choose δ such that |f(z)| > δ
>   for z on the circle |z−z0| = ρ. Since fk(z) converges uniformly on the
>   disc we have chosen, we can find N such that |fk(z)| ≥ δ/2 for every k
>   ≥ N, ensuring that the quotient fk′(z)/fk(z) is well defined for all z
>   on the circle |z−z0| = ρ. By Morera's theorem we have a uniform
>   convergence:
>
> $$\frac{f_{k}'(z)}{f_{k}(z)} \to \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}.$$ ..........

But I don't know why it is a uniform convergence. (I think that Morera's theorem is not relevant.) Why does it hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, Morera's theorem is not relevant here. What is relevant is Weierstraß' theorem that locally uniform convergence of a sequence of holomorphic functions implies locally uniform convergence of the sequences of derivatives,

$$f_k \xrightarrow{\text{loc. unif.}} f \Rightarrow f_k^{(n)} \xrightarrow{\text{loc. unif.}} f^{(n)}$$

for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Since the $\lvert f_k\rvert$ are bounded below by $\delta/2 > 0$ on $\{\lvert z-z_0\rvert = \rho\}$, that implies uniform convergence

$$\frac{f_k'}{f_k} \to \frac{f'}{f}$$

on $\{\lvert z-z_0\rvert = \rho\}$.

Answer (score 1):

According to "*Weierstrass'* theorem" $f_k' \to f'$ uniformly of compact sets. I think this should have been written there instead of "*Morera's* theorem".